# Need help in understanding this postscript code: what is the order in which the code should be executed?

Tags: postscript

```
0 5 360 5 mul {sin} for
stack
quit
```

I understand that we have a for loop with a range from 0 --> 360 with increments of 5. However, the `5 mul` is confusing.Why is it before the for loops body? The `5 mul` is applied to what? Where is the first argument? i.e: `4 5 mul` which is 4 x 5 = 20.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument is — guess what — 360:

```
0 5 1800 {sin} for stack quit
```

PostScript is stack oriented, and there's no special syntax for the `for` loop. You can therefore specify any expressions for the first three values. This would make it iterate 360 times, from 0 to 1800 (which is 360×5), with the step of 5. I don't know why it does this, though.

Answer (score 1):

(Not an answer, but need formatting.)

PostScript is a stack-oriented language. Operators take the number of arguments they expect from the stack. You can play with this in an interpreter like Ghostscript:

```
GS> 5 360 mul
GS<1> stack
1800
```

At this point the stack is [1800].

If you provide more arguments than an operator takes those values are *still* on the stack waiting for something else to happen:

```
GS> 0 5 360 5 mul
GS<3> stack
1800
5
0
```

Since `mul` takes two values it will just pop `5` and `360`, do the multiplication, and push the answer onto the stack. I.e., before the `mul`, your stack is this:

```
GS> 0 5 360 5
GS<4> stack
5
360
5
0
```

If you did a `mul` now you'd end up with the same thing:

```
GS<4> mul
GS<3> stack
1800
5
0
```

Then the code continues on as before, with the `{sin} for`.

You can do all the commands at once, as you show, or do it later--the stack is just the stack: it's modified as you go. So whether you do it like this:

```
GS> 0 5 360 5 mul { sin } for
GS<361>
```

Or

```
GS> 0 5 360 5
GS<4> mul
GS<3> { sin }
GS<4> for
GS<361>
```

you'll end up with the same thing.

In GhostScript (gs) the number in `<nnn>` is the current stack depth.

Stack-based languages can be a bit confusing if you're not used to the paradigm (or older HP calculators :) Forth is the canonical example of a stack-based language (and it's awesome). I miss the Forth and PostScript days (I used to write printers, and used Forth heavily in embedded systems). There are more-modern stack-based languages as well (Kitten, Factor).